# How VS2022 C# debugger shows values for uninitialized variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

The image below shows a C3 piece of code while debugging.
Current execution line is **678**
2 variables `cur_support_areas` and `cur_resistance_areas` are defined below on lines **684**, **685**

How the debugger shows values for variables that were not initialized yet?

[image: screenshot showing debug window with values for variables in question]

Comment: Is C3 supposed to read C#? You may want to include the text of the code in addition to the image for those unable to see (well or at all).

Comment: If you're in a loop the vars might still have their values from the last assignment and thus aren't necessarily uninititalized.

Comment: @JürgenRöhr Indeed. weird for me though. If you will post a Replay i will mark it an an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jurgen mentioned, this situation may comes from last assigned value.

Watch window might seem unintuitive in this situation, you can use ***System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()*** to output the value to the output window, this will help you view the history of the value changing:

[image]